# How to load HTML string into Chromium browser in "Delphi 10 Seattle"

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle, tchromium

The following code is written for loading the HTML string (as Stream) into `TWebBrowser`:

```
procedure TfrmTestDialog.LoadDocumentFromStream(const Stream: TStream);
var  
        PersistStreamInit: IPersistStreamInit;
        StreamAdapter: IStream;
begin  
  if not Assigned(dWebBrowser.Document) then Exit;
  // Get IPersistStreamInit interface on document object 
  if dWebBrowser.Document.QueryInterface(IPersistStreamInit, 
    PersistStreamInit) = S_OK then
  begin
    // Clear document
    if PersistStreamInit.InitNew = S_OK then
    begin
      // Get IStream interface on stream
      StreamAdapter:= TStreamAdapter.Create(Stream);
      // Load data from Stream into WebBrowser
      PersistStreamInit.Load(StreamAdapter);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

But i need to achieve this in TChromium browser.

Anyone please help me on this...

Comment: Maybe you should post your question in CEF44Delphi forum at https://www.briskbard.com/forum/

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the stream to a string using TStringStream :

```
function StreamToString(Stream: TStream): String;
begin
    with TStringStream.Create('') do
    try
        CopyFrom(Stream, Stream.Size - Stream.Position);
        Result := DataString;
    finally
        Free;
    end;
end;
```

That function is available here :
http://embarcadero.newsgroups.archived.at/public.delphi.vcl.components.using/200907/0907292775.html

Then call TChromium.LoadString to load the resulting string as you can see in the MiniBrowser demo :
https://github.com/salvadordf/CEF4Delphi/blob/7798f97872e4ca6f5246e3fdda04feeb990f88c7/demos/Delphi_VCL/MiniBrowser/uMiniBrowser.pas#L725

```
MyChromiumcomponent.LoadString(MyString);
```